# apt-get dist-upgrade, without overwriting my self compiled vim

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I'm using Ubuntu-14.04
I compiled vim myself (to add support for YouCompleteMe), and now when I execute apt-get dist-upgrade it overwrites my version of vim (and other dependent packages) and causes vim to stop working.

How can I upgrade everything, without ruining what I have compiled myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to keep things which you've compiled yourself in /usr/local/. Nothing from apt will be installed there so the stuff you've put in the directory will be safe from upgrades.

The other option is to [pin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) the `vim` package so that the upgrade will not install it (or any dependecies). This might work better if you `apt-get source` the vim, build the `.deb`, install it and then pin it rather than just overwriting `/usr/bin/vim` with your own compile.